# Logging to stdout with django under gunicorn

Tags: python, django, logging, gunicorn

I want to log to stdout all Django debug logs, the app is running in gunicorn using Docker.

Django config for logging:

```
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
            },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',  # change debug level as appropiate
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

And Im starting gunicorn with 
`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --log-level "debug" --capture-output --enable-stdio-inheritance tls.wsgi`

Comment: `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 tls.wsgi --access-logfile '-' --error-logfile '-' ...` '-' means log to stdout.

Comment: @bloodwithmilk yeah this makes gunicorn log to stdout/stderr but django logs are still not shown..

Comment: can you share your resolution?